# Find specific HTML tag combination with preg_match

Tags: php, html, regex, preg-match

I am trying to create a preg_match which finds a series of tags within a HTML document.

Example HTML:

```html
<div class="importantclass">
  <p>some thing</p>
  <p>some more things</p>
</div>
<div class="importantclass">
  <b>some text</b>
  <p>NEEDLE</p>
</div>
```

I need to find the combination of tags with the div class="importantclass" and a subsequent p-tag with a specific NEEDLE-Text inside.

I then need to return the position of the opening div class.
Note: I do not want to get a match because of the first occurance of the importantclass div.

**Is there a possibility doing this without using DOM and just using regexp?**

Thanks for your hints!

Comment: and why do you want to use a regex for that when you know that there is DOM which is the much more adequate tool for finding the nodes? Can you clarify the actual usecase, e.g. what do you intend to do with the offset once you have it?

Comment: I see how that answer got so popular now.... You shouldn't parse HTML with Regex, as Gordon stated, you have a perfectly good DOM with a `getElementsByTagName()` method that you can iterate through.

Comment: Can you please post a sample of the desired output ?

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you ?

```
<?php
    $html = <<< LOB
<div class="importantclass">
  <p>some thing</p>
  <p>some more things</p>
</div>
<div class="importantclass">
  <b>some text</b>
  <p>FIND ME</p>
</div>
LOB;

    $needle = "FIND ME";
    preg_match_all('%(<div.*?class="importantclass">.*?</div>)%sim', $html, $matches, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($matches[1]); $i++) {
        if (preg_match("%<p>$needle</p>%im", $matches[1][$i])) {
            echo "MATCH FOUND!<br>";
            echo "POSITION $i<br>";
            echo htmlentities( $matches[1][$i]);
        }
}
```

<kbd>[DEMO](http://ideone.com/uBZYJu)</kbd>